# Save or free memory by reducing use of variable?

Tags: ruby, performance, memory

I wonder if reducing the number of variables will greatly save or free memory. Sometimes I am torn between readable code, or performance.

For example in Ruby, is it better to code this:

```
  def touch_updated_at
    a = self.model_name
    a.touch
  end
```

or this:

```
  def touch_updated_at
    self.model_name.touch
  end
```

Taking in consideration that this function is only used in model or controller. No need of passing it to view. Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on count of this variables. Normally, you will see no difference for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no implementer of any ruby interpreter, but I think they're exactly the same.

A temporary local variable isn't likely to be garbage collected any earlier, whether it is named or not.

Unless `a` is actually a property, of course.

If you want to change speed or memory usage of this code, you should worry less about how it looks and more about what it does.

Answer (score 1):

The actual objects will probably have a bigger impact on memory than the variables which reference them.

The lifetime of a variable is determined by its scope:

- Local
- Closure
- Object
- Class
- Constant
- Global

Objects, however, are only freed by the garbage collector when all variables referencing it are gone. Also, they will probably consume much more memory than a reference.

You can think of variables as numbers that identify the object. The memory they use is small enough to be negligible. I suppose the interpreter might also optimize them away.

```
def touch_updated_at
  model_name.touch
end
```

Even though this usage will not improve memory usage significantly, it *is* much more concise.